# What graphics card to I need to use WebGL

Tags: graphics, 3d, hardware, webgl

Maybe there is a combo hardware & WebGl guru out there that can help me out.

I want to experiement with WebGL, I updated my Chrome Browser to the latest,
which seems to support most of the new HTML5 & CSS3 standards.

When I go to any WebGL samples, it says my graphics card doesn't support it.

I am on a Sony Vaio AW11M, with a NVidia GeForce 9300M GS

I did some googling on Graphics Cards for WebGL and could not find anything much
out there.  Perhaps I can update some Cuda drivers or something or I really do 
need to get a new laptop.

regards

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows Vista Home Premium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically point people at http://get.webgl.org/ for this kind of thing.

It will link you through to the appropriate page for configuring your browser, which may include information about blacklisted graphics cards like [this one](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=1220892).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be [this](http://code.google.com/p/webgl-globe/issues/detail?id=1) problem. Access the URL `about:flags` url and enable the `GPU accelerated compositing` option, as suggested in the link.

Comment: Is that:                                                            GPU compositing on all pages Mac, Windows, Linux
Uses GPU accelerated compositing on all pages, not just those that include GPU-accelerated layers.                                                I enabled this from default and no joy.